# Re-directing after sign-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**Background,**

So I have an Ruby on Rails + VueJS application. It's an e-commmerce site that requires users to sign into their accounts - before they can checkout and pay. However, the "checkout" button is clickable to non-signed in users but when they click it they are prompted with a modal pop-up to sign in. Once they're signed in they have to click the "Checkout" button again which isn't the most user-friendly approach.

**Question,**

How can I re-direct the user to the checkout page upon signing in after they've clicked the "Checkout" button and have signed in. Instead of the current way it works where they have to click the "checkout" button and then sign in and then have to click the "checkout" button again once signed in to get to the checkout page. It would be nice to re-direct directly to checkout page as soon as they're signed in successfully.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure where to begin here as I've never done a re-direct to a specific page after sign-in, that was clicked before signing-in, is this possible?

Any ideas would be super helpful!

Comment: If the signin is ajax you can check the sucess login response and then redirect with javascript with `window.location.href = "/other/page";`

Comment: what do you use to sign users in? devise?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use function redirect_to like this:

```
redirect_to "http:/checkoutpage.com"
```

Here is the documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html